# How to assign the following rule?

Tags: replacement, syntax, rule, assignment

Consider the following object: `function[x,a,b]`. It is a symbol carrying one "coordinate" x and two indices `a,b`.

I would like to make the rule `Der`

```
D[function[x,a,b],function[x,c,f]] -> KroneckerDelta[a, c]KroneckerDelta[b,f]
```

in order to apply it to an arbitrary object `obj` containing `function` and its powers (a scalar expression, a matrix, etc.), `Der[obj,function[x,c,f]]`. Say, an example of the object is

```
obj=function[x,a,b]*function[x,a,c]*coefficient[b,c] +function[x,a,c]^2
```

For which the result of applying the rule should be

```
Der[obj,function[x,c,f]] = KroneckerDelta[a,c]KroneckerDelta[b,f]function[x,a,c]coefficient[b,c] + KroneckerDelta[a,c]KroneckerDelta[c,f]function[x,a,b]coefficient[b,c]+2function[x,a,c]*KroneckerDelta[a,c]KroneckerDelta[c,f]
```

Could you please tell me how to do this?

My attempt is to use `UpSetDelayed`:

```
D[function[x_, a_, b_], function[x_, c_, f_]] ^:= 
 KroneckerDelta[a, c] KroneckerDelta[b, f]
```

It works if derivating just `function[x, a, b]`, but fails if there is any difference from the pattern. Say, if `function[x, a, b]` is a summand in some scalar expression, or it is inside a matrix (please see also [this question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/288297/why-the-replacement-rule-works-okay-for-scalars-but-not-okay-for-matrices)).

Comment: Note just for clarity that you are using [`UpSetDelayed`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/UpSetDelayed.html) and not `TagSetDelayed`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can make use of the [`NonConstants`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NonConstants) option to D:

```
function /: D[function[x,a_,b_], function[x,c_,f_], OptionsPattern[]] := If[
    MemberQ[OptionValue[NonConstants], function],
    KroneckerDelta[a,c] KroneckerDelta[b,f],
    0
]
```

Then  either:

```
D[obj, function[x, c, f], NonConstants->{function}]
```

> coefficient[b, c] function[x, a, c] KroneckerDelta[a, c] KroneckerDelta[b,
> f] + coefficient[b, c] function[x, a, b] KroneckerDelta[a,
> c] KroneckerDelta[c, f] +
> 2 function[x, a, c] KroneckerDelta[a, c] KroneckerDelta[c, f]

or:

```
SetOptions[D, NonConstants->{function}];
D[obj, function[x, c, f]]
```

> coefficient[b, c] function[x, a, c] KroneckerDelta[a, c] KroneckerDelta[b,
> f] + coefficient[b, c] function[x, a, b] KroneckerDelta[a,
> c] KroneckerDelta[c, f] +
> 2 function[x, a, c] KroneckerDelta[a, c] KroneckerDelta[c, f]

should do what you want.