# How to define the following "derivative"?

Tags: symbolic, syntax, rule

Consider the following test expression:

```
exprtest = 
  f[x, a1]^2*f[x, a2]^2 + f[x, a1] d[x, a1] + f[x, a2] c[x, a2] + 
   df[x, a1, a2]*dc[x, a1, a2] + df[x, b3, c4] dc[x, b3, c4] + 
   df[x, b5, c9] dd[x, b5, c9];
```

It is made of "fields" `f,c,d` and their "derivatives" `df,dc,dd` (and may also include some constants `tensor[a,b,c,d]`). The "field" depends on a some parameter `x` and an "index" `a`, while the "derivative" depends on two indices `a,b`. In `exprtest`, different labels for the indices are used.

Let us define the symbols for "fields" and "derivatives":

```
{Fsymbol["f", x, a_] = f[x, a], Fsymbol["c", x, a_] = c[x, a], 
  Fsymbol["d", x, a_] = d[x, a]};
{dFsymbol["f", x, a_, b_] = df[x, a, b], 
  dFsymbol["c", x, a_, b_] = dc[x, a, b], 
  dFsymbol["d", x, a_, b_] = dd[x, a, b]};
```

Let us also define the list of labels of the indices that are used in `exprtest`:

```
indiceslist = {a1, a2, b3, c4, b5, c9};
```

I would like to compute the derivative `Der[field,index]` of `exprtest` with respect to the "field" and "derivative" which, in addition to the standard differentiation rules (like $dx^{4}/dx = 4x^{3}$), replaces `field[x,a_]*expr[a_,...]` with `expr[index]` and `fieldderivative[x,a_,b_]*expr[a_,b_,...]` with `i*p[fieldlabel,a]expr[a,index,...]`.

This is how I implement it:

```
Der[field_, index_] := 
 Sum[D[exprtest, Fsymbol[field, x, indiceslist[[i]]]] + 
    Sum[I*p[field, indiceslist[[j]]]*
      D[exprtest, 
       dFsymbol[field, x, indiceslist[[j]], indiceslist[[i]]]], {j, 1,
       Length[indiceslist], 1}] /. {indiceslist[[i]] -> index}, {i, 1,
    Length[indiceslist], 1}]
Der["f", \[Kappa]]
```

> I p(f,a1) dc(x,a1,[Kappa])+2 f(x,a1)^2 f(x,[Kappa])+2 f(x,a2)^2 f(x,[Kappa])+I p(f,b3) dc(x,b3,[Kappa])+I p(f,b5) dd(x,b5,[Kappa])+c(x,[Kappa])+d(x,[Kappa])

It first sums the differentiation by the fields (and derivatives) with indices labels occurring in the Lagrangian, and then replaces the labels with the desired final label.

But it is ugly and slow, introducing two summations over the possible labels. In addition, the list of labels may be very broad and changing, so it may be complicated to define it from the very beginning (and hence use my realization).

Could you please tell me if there is an analog of my `Der` function that does not care about different labels for the indices and, in particular, does not involve the summation of the labels occurring in `exprtest`?

Comment: First, I don't think you need to define all those `Fsymbol` and `dFsymbol`. Instead of `Fsymbol[field, x, i]`, you can just write `field[x, i]`. And instead of `dFsymbol[field, x, i, j]`, you write `Symbol["d" <> ToString[field]][x, i, j]`. Second, no need to manually define `indiceslist`, just retrieve them from the expression: `indiceslist = DeleteDuplicates[Flatten[Rest@*List @@@ Variables[exprtest]]]`.

Comment: `Der[field_, index_] := Sum[D[exprtest, field[x, indiceslist[[i]]]] + Sum[I*p[field, indiceslist[[j]]]*D[exprtest, Symbol["d" <> ToString[field]][x, indiceslist[[j]], indiceslist[[i]]]], {j, 1, Length[indiceslist], 1}] /. {indiceslist[[i]] -> index}, {i, 1, Length[indiceslist], 1}]`

Comment: @Domen : Thanks! Please also take a look at my version of the solution (the answer below).

Comment: @Domen : the problem with the summation inside `Der` is that it is potentially slow in the cases when I have a lot of summands in the polynomial.

Comment: Is it just _potentially_ slow or is it _actually_ slow?

Comment: @Domen : Naively, I would expect that iterating the derivative over `n` indices would slow down `Der` by `n` times compared to a hypothetical `DerOptimal` where there is no sum over derivatives.

Comment: @Domen : If powering `exprtest` by 30 and removing the last string in the definition of `Der1` (with Kroneckers replacement), it is ~3 times faster than `Der`. So yes, `Der` is definitely slow. (in my purposes, the last string of `Der1` may be applied in the very end, after several applications of `Der1` when the final expression is short).

Comment: But ... even for `exprtest^30`, the calculation time is ~0.5 ms ... How is that slow? Do you really need to optimize this?

Comment: @Domen : it is 30 s in my case (Mathematica 13.1@Windows 11). Before computing, I do `exprtest^30//Expand` (this is how these polynomials are predefined in my case). Simplifying them would take too much time.

Comment: @Domen : in addition, `indexlist` as you defined it may recover the indices in a wrong way if there are some parametric coefficients in front of "fields" and "derivatives": together with indices, it includes all possible parameters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I still think there is nothing particularly wrong with your code apart from it being written a bit clumsily.

Let me summarize the main improvements:

1. Use `Sum[...i..., {i, indiceslist}]` instead of `Sum[...indiceslist[[i]]..., {i, 1, Length[indiceslist], 1}]`.
2. No need to define all those `Fsymbol` and `dFsymbol`. Although it would be more convenient if you used some other construction for derivatives (for example `d[f, x, a, b]` or `d[f][x, a, b]` instead of concatenating symbol names `df[x, a, b]`), you can still programmaticaly construct the derivative with `Symbol["d" <> ToString[field]][x, j, i]`.
3. No need to manually construct `indiceslist` when you can extract all indices directly from the expression.
4. Do not expand the powers before differentiating; do it afterwards.

The code is then:

```
Der[expr_, x_, field_, index_] := Module[{indices},
  indices = Complement[DeleteDuplicates[Cases[Variables[exprtest],
             _[lst__] :> lst]], {x}];

  Sum[D[expr, field[x, i]] + 
    Sum[I*p[field, j]*
       D[expr, Symbol["d" <> ToString[field]][x, j, i]] /. {i -> index}, 
     {j, indices}], {i, indices}]
  ]

Der[exprtest, x, f, κ]
(* c[x, a2] + d[x, a1] + 2 f[x, a1]^2 f[x, a2] + 2 f[x, a1] f[x, a2]^2 + 
   I dc[x, a1, κ] p[f, a1] + I dc[x, b3, κ] p[f, b3] + 
   I dd[x, b5, κ] p[f, b5] *)
```

The code is still very fast for powers if you just don't expand them prior to differentiation.

```
(res1 = Der[exprtest^30, f, κ]) // AbsoluteTiming // First
(* 0.003008 *)
(res2 = Der[exprtest^30 // Expand, f, κ]) // AbsoluteTiming // First
(* 12.8399 *)

Simplify[res1 - res2]
(* 0 *)
```

Answer (score 0):

I came up with a version of the solution. It uses [this answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/288308/41058).

So first, I define the rules for derivatives of "fields" and their "derivatives" with respect to the corresponding "fields":

```
f /: D[f[x_, a_], f[x_, b_], OptionsPattern[]] := 
 If[MemberQ[OptionValue[NonConstants], f], KroneckerDelta[a, b], 0]
df /: D[df[x_, a_, b_], f[x_, c_], OptionsPattern[]] := 
 If[MemberQ[OptionValue[NonConstants], df], 
  I*p["f", a] KroneckerDelta[b, c], 0]
c /: D[c[x_, a_], c[x_, b_], OptionsPattern[]] := 
 If[MemberQ[OptionValue[NonConstants], c], KroneckerDelta[a, b], 0]
dc /: D[dc[x_, a_, b_], c[x_, c_], OptionsPattern[]] := 
 If[MemberQ[OptionValue[NonConstants], dc], 
  I*p["c", a] KroneckerDelta[b, c], 0]
d /: D[d[x_, a_], d[x_, b_], OptionsPattern[]] := 
 If[MemberQ[OptionValue[NonConstants], d], KroneckerDelta[a, b], 0]
dd /: D[dd[x_, a_, b_], d[x_, c_], OptionsPattern[]] := 
 If[MemberQ[OptionValue[NonConstants], dd], 
  I*p["d", a] KroneckerDelta[b, c], 0]
```

Then, I compute the derivative:

```
Der1[field_, index_] := Block[{},
  expr10 = 
   D[exprtest, Fsymbol[field, x, index], 
    NonConstants -> {Fsymbol[field, x, a][[0]], 
      dFsymbol[field, x, a, b][[0]]}];
  expr10 //. e_*KroneckerDelta[x_, y_] :> (e /. x -> y)
  ]
If[Der1["f", \[Kappa]] == Der["f", \[Kappa]], "True"]
```

The problem with this solution is that I would need to define a huge number of rules manually, for all the "fields" and the "derivatives" that are present in the expression. For three "fields" and "derivatives", I already need to type 6 long strings of code manually. But in the real case, I have 20-30 "fields".

If powering `exprtest` by 30 and removing the last string in the definition of `Der1` (with Kroneckers replacement), it is ~3 times faster than `Der`. With this line being included, however, `Der1` is even somewhat slower than `Der`. So neither `Der` nor `Der1` are optimal: `Der` suffers from the summation of the derivative of the same huge expression over indices, while `Der1` - from the symbolic replacements (the derivative itself is much faster).

Comment: If you need to manually write the same thing three times, you should probably [automatize it](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_three_(computer_programming)).